# MongoDb Upsert in Spring removes properties set to null

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

Consider the following Java Class.

```
class Transaction {
@Id
public String id;
public String firstProperty;
public String secondProperty;
}
```

In Java following code is executed :
(mongoTemplate is of type Mongoperations)

```
Transaction transaction = new Transaction("T1");
transaction.setFirstProperty("first");
Query query = Query.query(Criteria.where("_id").is("T1"));
DBObject dbObject = new BasicDBObject();
mongoTemplate.getConverter().write(transactionInfo, dbObject);
Update update = Update.fromDBObject(dbObject);
mongoTemplate.upsert(query , update , TransactionInfo.class);
```

Following document is created.

```
{
_id:123,
firstProperty: "first"
}
```

If this piece of code is executed later :

```
Transaction transaction = new Transaction("T1");
transaction.setSecondProperty("second");
Query query = Query.query(Criteria.where("_id").is("T1"));
mongoTemplate.upsert(query , update , TransactionInfo.class);
```

Expected Document :

```
{
_id:123,
firstProperty: "first",
secondProperty: "second"
}
```

Actual Document:

```
{
_id:123,
secondProperty: "second"
}
```

From what I read in MongoDB docs I expect the document to be  updated with "secondProperty" but it results in the removal of "firstProperty" . I think the document is getting created again, instead of getting updated. Please let me know if I am missing something.

Comment: checkout this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20001627/mongotemplate-upsert-easy-way-to-make-update-from-pojo-which-user-has-editted

Comment: What is the update object has . Please post that too .. you have mentioned about Query  object only ... whats there in update object

Comment: or try to use mongoTemplate.findAndModify

Comment: What is the value of `update` in the `mongoTemplate.upsert(query , update , TransactionInfo.class)`?

Comment: I have added the update object. (I actually use save operation (CustomRepository). But save will also perform a upsert operation under the hood)